# Why does my directory not change in my node.js command prompt?

Tags: node.js

I just configured node.js and npm. However, the command

cd "D:\directory_name"

does not change my directory to the specified one. I retried the command without the "" quotation signs. I am attaching a screenshot.

Thanks in Advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbxGW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to point drive name after or before that.

like below.

D: // enter

You could not just move to another drive's folder directory.

Need to point drive out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not already in drive D, then you cannot see the path change until you navigate to D.

```
H:>cd d:\Users\
H:\>d:
d:\Users>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using windows, try commands in this sequence

**cd "D:\directory_name"**

**cd D:**